# Grafana alert from percentage CPU/Memory usage

Tags: alert, grafana, promql

I want to make an alert through Grafana that define if the CPU or Memory usage above threshold (let say 85%) it will firing an alert. What I have now are time series limit CPU/memory

`kube_pod_container_resource_limits{namespace="$namespace", pod="$pod", resource="cpu"}`

and pod resource usage

`sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="$namespace", pod="$pod", container!="POD", container!="", pod!=""}[1m]))`

Logical to make the percentage is, `(resource_usage_query)/(resource_limit_query)*100`. I've tried to combine both query same as the formula but ended with `nodata` value. Is there any syntax or something I missed? I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ending with no data because the metrics have different labels.
You need to aggregate both by e g: pod , then do the division.
This should fix your problem. Something like: (I didn't test it)

`sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="$namespace", pod="$pod", container!="POD", container!="", pod!=""}[1m])) by (pod) / sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits{namespace="$namespace", pod="$pod", resource="cpu"}) by (pod) * 100`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I need to measure the current usage from limit given before to the pod. By that, maybe what you mean is ```sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="$namespace", pod="$pod", container!="POD", container!="", pod!=""}[1m]))/sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits{namespace="$namespace", pod="$pod", resource="cpu"}) by (pod)*100```, is it?

Comment: Yeap, as I mentioned I didn't test it, I just want to show you that different labels was the problem. I edit the answer

Comment: If it helped, please consider marking as answered